Operators "new" and "delete" in C++
I ran into a problem, from an exercise in Bjarne Stroustrup's book Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd edition), at the very end of chapter 17 for the Exercises section, exercise 7:
The program works normally if you do not use delete linearray1;.
Accordingly, the problem is when deleting the allocated dynamic memory.
I have no error messages or warnings in the console.
However, VS Code shows me that problem in this line (delete linearray1).
Highlights the entire line in yellow.
Tell me how to solve the problem in this case. How can I correctly clear the allocated memory?
#include <iostream> 

void fillarray(std::string& array)
{ 
    char* linearray1 {new char};
    char* line = linearray1;
    std::cin >> line;
    
    while (*line)
    {   
        if (*line == '!')
            break;
        array += *line;
        line++;
    }
    delete linearray1;
}

int main()
{

    std::string linearray1;
    fillarray(linearray1);
    std::cout << "\n" << linearray1;
    return 0;
}


char* linearray1 {new char}; creates a pointer to a single char.  Why are you trying to mix std::string and  manual memory management of c-style arrays?

@RichardCritten Hi!
I used C-string and string based on the assignment in Stroustrup's book. Even if you use only c-strings, the problem remains the same. In addition, when allocating memory of a fixed size, the problem when clearing memory remains exactly the same.

I have not needed to use new in a real C++ program in 13 years.  Use smart pointers.  The smart pointer for strings that manages the memory backing store for you is called std::string.

@Eljay I understand that it is better to use a string, but based on the task I have to solve the problem under certain conditions. And the conditions are such that I have to understand why an error occurs in the line - delete linearray1. Can you explain this particular problem?
The book is:
Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition) B. Stroustrup
Chapter 17 Exercise. 7

The problem is not on the line with delete. The problem is that you allocated only space for one char (basically, only enough to hold the NUL terminator), but tries to read a string from cin to it, which is UB and anything can happen. That removing the delete line makes the program appears to work proves nothing. It still has UB without the delete line.

Tell me how to solve the problem in this case, . how can I correctly clear the allocated memory? -- Why do you think the issue has anything to do with clearing the allocated memory?  You allocated for a single char, but you are trying to place characters in the space that was not allocated.

The program works normally if you do not use - delete linearray1; -- No it doesn't.  All the delete did was hide the actual bug.

Simpler example, showing the bug.

@marcusreed Here is the exercise:  Write a program that reads characters from cin into an array that you allocate on the free store. Read individual characters until an exclamation mark (I) is entered. Do not use a std : :string. Do not worry about memory exhaustion -- Why are you using a std::string when the exercise says to not use one?

@Eljay
Initially, I defined a function to find the length of a string, i.e. it returned an integer operator. Then i used char* linearray1 { new char[mysize(l)] } "l" - it's an argument of function. That is, I used a variable to specify the size of the allocated memory. But then I encountered an error and decided to abandon this method, moved to a method to simply allocate 1 cell in memory. It turns out that in order to work correctly with din. memory. we must always specify a constant value when allocating it?

@PaulMcKenzie Paul, I'm so sorry it's Ex. 8. Unfortunately, the book is at home, I am at work.
I had to look for an electronic edition.

But even exercise 8 says you can use a std::string, but says nothing about having to use dynamically allocated memory.   A std::string knows how to handle the memory itself -- it needs no "outside help" to do this.  Thus you just made a simple solution overly complicated.  To quote from the version of the book I have for exercise 8: -- Do exercise 7 again, but this time read into a std: : string rather than to memory you put on the free store (string knows how to use the free store
for you)..

"Then i used char* linearray1 { new char[mysize(l)] }" That is not what you showed in the question. Initially you have an error, what error? You'd better fix that instead. Allocating a single char is not the correct way.

@marcus - No, if we have a constant size, we hardly ever need dynamic allocations. So a variable for the size is the standard way.

@marcusreed  -- Anyway, if what you coded was the solution to exercise 7, I'm sorry to say that you need to go back to exercise 7 and make the corrections that have already been mentioned.  Exercise 8 can be shown as the reason why exercise 7 is not how modern C++ programs are written, all due to the mistakes being made.

@Paul, I listened to your opinion and had to go back to the 4th exercise.
Where I have to duplicate the line into new. dynamic memory.
Here I get the same error, I try to allocate dynamic memory using the function to determine the length of the line.
I want to emphasize that when deleting a line: *line0 = '\0';
delete operation  works correctly!
Link with this code: https://codefile.io/f/HNBGDWbsYq

@marcusreed *I want to emphasize that when deleting a line: line0 = '\0'; delete operation works correctly! -- No it doesn't.  There is this piece of important information you are missing -- when you use manual memory management, if you write beyond or outside the bounds of the allocated memory, there is no guarantee that your "works".  You are invoking undefined behavior.  I took your code, commented out the line you mentioned, and ran it under a sanitizer -- you see that you are corrupting memory.

And speaking of undefined behavior, C++ (and C) are the rare languages where this occurs.  If you expected that automatically some sort of error popup or exception is thrown when you make these types of mistakes, you are mistaken.  This is why C++ is a complex language, unlike probably most others.  With Java, python, C#, etc. you make a mistake, you know right away by having an exception thrown or similar -- not so with C++.

How does this Compiler Explorer solution work for you in your VSCode?  If you are still getting a highlight yellow line for the delete, then I suspect there is something else causing that in your editor's environment.

@PaulMcKenzie   That's not really true.  Most programming languages have some corners where their behaviour is undefined.  Yes, Java, Python, etc give a defined behaviour in numerous cases where C++ (and C) have undefined behaviour, but each also has other corners (edge cases) where their behaviour is undefined, and their documentation either omits that fact, or documents it in a manner that is hard to recognise.  Some, like Eiffel, document an "open problem" (in the sense that practically defining/implementing a behaviour is an ongoing topic of research).

It is true that a lot of cases of undefined behaviour in C and C++ could - with knowledge available now, but not when they were originally specified - be removed or made well-defined in the language (or library).     In some cases, however, they are retained, because the effort to turn undefined behaviour into something less (well) undefined hasn't caught up, or the proposals to do so have unwanted/unintended effects in terms of breaking other language features.  Sometimes there is simply unresolved dispute over which competing option to choose.

To summarize the comments...
In fillarray(), you are allocating dynamic memory for only 1 char, and then passing that buffer to the operator>> overload that reads a word into a char[] buffer.  That overload will try to read and output more than 1 char (including a '\0' terminator) until it encounters a whitespace character that ends the input.  So, you end up invoking undefined behavior by writing out of bounds of your dynamic memory, thus corrupting surrounding memory. And in this case, delete seems to be just an unwitting victim of that behavior.
If you really want to read the input 1 char at a time, then use the operator>> overload that reads a single char, or use the istream::get(char&) method instead, eg:
void fillarray(std::string& array)
{ 
    char* pch {new char};
    
    while ((std::cin >> *pch) && (*pch != '!'))
    // or: while (std::cin.get(*pch) && (*pch != '!'))
    {   
        array += *pch;
    }

    delete pch;
}

But, there is no need to dynamically allocate 1 char by itself, just use a local char variable instead, eg:
void fillarray(std::string& array)
{ 
    char ch;
    
    while ((std::cin >> ch) && (ch != '!'))
    // or: while (std::cin.get(ch) && (ch != '!'))
    {   
        array += ch;
    }
}

However, in this particular example, you can just read directly into your target std::string by using std::getline() instead, eg:
void fillarray(std::string& array)
{ 
    std::getline(std::cin, array, '!');
}


Remy!Remy! Thank you very much for your time!
The problem was actually a little different, all because of my carelessness!
By the way, I figured it all out and am going to write a full answer to my own question later
Your answer turned out to be very interesting in terms of choosing an alternative for solving this problem. I will take it into account when writing subsequent works.
Thanks again!
